# mergeing two sharepoint rest json-response result sets

Tags: json, sharepoint, odata

I'm using the sharepoint rest api to get list items in a paginated format (with the return type as json).

say, I've already got one set of the response of 100 items , and I call again for the next hundred, how do I append the next hundered items to the result set.

Tried this but I get an error:

```
var MasterList + = data.d.result; // I get an error saying ";" expected
```

where MAsterList already contains data.d.result from the previous ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

If both are arrays you could concatenate these together, using:

```
MasterList = [].concat(MasterList, data.d.results);
```

The error you are getting is probably the fact that you initialize your var with +=, which looks improbable to me...